# font-size using rem in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm trying to figure out how to get chrome to use rem in font-size css.

Following the structure shown in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/linearly-scale-font-size-with-css-clamp-based-on-the-viewport/), I define my font size as:

```
font-size:   clamp(1rem, -0.875rem + 8.333vw, 1.3rem);
```

When I run this in the local environment, it renders as expected in chrome, firefox and safari. When deployed, it renders as expected in firefox and safari. In chrome, the text is tiny.

Is there an extra step required to get chrome to use rem in css?

I've seen very old posts talking about problems using rem with media queries in chrome - but cannot find current issues that may be blocking chrome from rendering font size.

Comment: Strange one :( , I don't gave an answer for you unfortunately, I just wanted to mention that I heard that `em`s are the best units to use in media queries, as you can see here https://zellwk.com/blog/media-query-units/ . But anyways that article would not suggest anything wrong with Chrome and `rem`s. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say for 100%, but it seems like some local issue that relates to Chrome Extensions or something else. Please check your project, as well as example below in incognito mode with turned off extensions.

In example below you can make sure that's issue not in REM, and compare it with EM.

```css
.with-rem {
  font-size:   clamp(1rem, -0.875rem + 8.333vw, 1.3rem);
}
.with-em {
  font-size:   clamp(1em, -0.875em + 8.333vw, 1.3em);
}

li {
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>This list item not styled</li>
  <li class="with-rem">This list item styled with REM</li>
  <li class="with-em">This list item styled with EM</li>
</ul>
```